# How to direct top-level menu to second-level menu and have the top-level menu have unique name?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, admin, submenu

**Goal**

In Wordpress, I am attempting to have *Admin Menus* automatically create if they are in a *Menu* from "Appearance -> Menus". This, I was able to develop.

The part in which I am having troubles with is due to its specificity. I am attempting to have a *top-level menu* direct to a *second-level menu* AND have the *top-level menu* maintain its original name.

**Code**

Setup in "Appearance -> Menu"

```
Callsigns
    -> Alpha
    -> Bravo
    -> Charlie
```

The *top-level menu* "Callsigns" has modified options. The *Navigation Label* is "Alpha" and the *Title Attribute* is "Callsigns".

functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'register_my_menus' );
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus( array('admin-menus' => 'Admin Menus'));
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_menus');
function my_admin_menus() {
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations['admin-menus']);
    $pages = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if ($page->menu_item_parent == 0)
            add_menu_page(
                $page->title,
                $page->attr_title ? $page->attr_title : $page->title,
                'read',
                sanitize_title($page->title),
                'admin_page_format'
            );
        else
            add_submenu_page(
                sanitize_title($page->menu_item_parent->title),        // ISSUE
                $page->title,
                $page->attr_title ? $page->attr_title : $page->title,
                'read',
                sanitize_title($page->title),
                'admin_page_format'
            );
    }
}
```

I marked the line is which I am fairly confident is the issue. Originally, I did not try to use "->" and as of now, I am fairly confident it is not possible to use "->" twice in a row like I did above.

**Incorrect Solutions**

```
sanitize_title($page->menu_item_parent->title)
```

The *top-level menu* works. It has the correct name and directs to the correct *second-level menu*. However, the *second-level menus* do not show up as an admin menu at all.

```
sanitize_title(get_the_title($page->menu_item_parent))
```

Same outcome as the above incorrect solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'register_my_menus' );
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus( array('admin-menus' => 'Admin Menus'));
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_menus');
function my_admin_menus() {
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations['admin-menus']);
    $pages = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

    function get_menu_page($pages, $id) {
        foreach ($pages as $page)
            if ($page->ID == $id) return $page;
    }

    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if ($page->menu_item_parent == 0)
            add_menu_page(
                $page->title,
                $page->attr_title ? $page->attr_title : $page->title,
                'read',
                sanitize_title($page->title),
                'admin_page_format'
            );
        else
            add_submenu_page(
                sanitize_title(get_menu_page($pages, $page->menu_item_parent)->title),
                $page->title,
                $page->attr_title ? $page->attr_title : $page->title,
                'read',
                sanitize_title($page->title),
                'admin_page_format'
            );
    }
}
```

The solution was to create a function that went the *Menu Loop* again to return the object of the page.

I doubt this is the cleanest way but this is the only thing I could come up with.